# Changing value of singleton variable in destructor for a different class php

Tags: php, destructor

I have a destructor method that empties an array in a different class when the destructor gets called.

```
public function __destruct()
{
    SingletonClass::instance()->removeAllData();
    // Printing out the value of getAllData here prints 0
}
```

The problem with this the data within the singleton class doesn't seem to get permanently altered when I run a stub script like this:

```
echo count(SingletonClass::instance()->getAllData()); // Prints 0
$otherClass = new OtherClass();
SingletonClass::instance()->createDataAssociatedWith($otherClass);
echo count(SingletonClass::instance()->getAllData()); // Prints 1

$i = 4850;
while ($i--)
{
    $otherClass = new OtherClass();
    // Destructor runs during this loop. If the count of getAllData is logged, 1 is always printed
}

echo count(SingletonClass::instance()->getAllData()); // Prints 1
```

It's as though the array is being emptied within the loop, but then somehow, after the loop is completed, the data is back in the array